# Playbutton animation

Tags: javascript, html, image, audio-player

I have one code that starts playing audio when I click on the image. I need help to edit it. I would like to make so when I click on the image it should start playing audio, but also change image to another. Do you know how to do it?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function playSound(el,soundfile) {
          if (el.mp3) {
              if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
              else el.mp3.pause();
          } else {
              el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
              el.mp3.play();
          }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
<span id="dummy" onclick="playSound(this, 'http://listen.shoutcast.com/newfm128mp3');">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e2aefa_1969d5f605404431bb558b4ff9e60966~mv2.png/v1/crop/x_10,y_33,w_52,h_51/fill/w_52,h_51,al_c/e2aefa_1969d5f605404431bb558b4ff9e60966~mv2.png" name="Bottom-1" width="50" height="45" border="0" id="Bottom-1"/>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      //Create new function that will update the image source on click.
      function updateImage(el, soundfile) {
          //Determine if music is playing or paused then adjust image source accordingly.
          if(soundfile.mp3.paused) {
              el.src = "pausedImageSrc";
          } else {
              el.src = "playImageSrc";
          }
      };

      function playSound(el,soundfile) {
          if (el.mp3) {
              if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
              else el.mp3.pause();
          } else {
              el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
              el.mp3.play();
          }
          //Call new function made whenever the sound is toggled.
          updateImage(document.getElementById("Bottom-1"), el);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
<span id="dummy" onclick="playSound(this, 'http://listen.shoutcast.com/newfm128mp3');">
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e2aefa_1969d5f605404431bb558b4ff9e60966~mv2.png/v1/crop/x_10,y_33,w_52,h_51/fill/w_52,h_51,al_c/e2aefa_1969d5f605404431bb558b4ff9e60966~mv2.png" name="Bottom-1" width="50" height="45" border="0" id="Bottom-1"/>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

All I simply did was add a new function called `updateImage` that changes the image src based upon if the audio is paused or not.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b0wgh4em/1/

Comment: Yeah something like that. But do you know how to do so image changes after first click? So at the beginning it should show "pausebutton" and when you click it shout change to "playbutton"